# Host a directory on a different server/domain

Tags: apache-2.2, domain-name-system, cname-record, github

I own a domain with a Apache server running Wordpress (example.com), whose configuration I can probably tweak (if I can propose a good solution).

I have a GitHub Pages hosting (example.github.io), whose server configuration I of course cannot touch (except some basics: http://bit.ly/1LZdhBT).

I want a specific directory of my domain (example.com/documentation) to point to my github.io site, without the user noticing (the point is the keep exiting URLs valid).

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

create a virtual host with proxy pass of the sub directory pointing to the github pages... should work seamlessly..

```
<VirtualHost example.com:80>
    ProxyPass /subdir http://example.github.io

</VirtualHost>
```

Rest place your directory directive and everything as is within the virtual host...
should work fine.

Comment: This looks promising! Thanks! Are there known limitations? Drawbacks? Also, how would it behave under SSL?

Comment: if you use ssl you need `SSLProxyEngine On`